# Using custom type for strings in google proto buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is it possible to instruct google proto buffer code generator to use a different type for string rather than the std string?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. The entire library would have to change to understand a new string type, not just the generated code.